# how to cancel an aws batch RUNNABLE job in javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

Suppose I have a job stuck at runnable status in aws batch. How to cancel it with [javascript sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/batch/)? Which one api from two below should I use?

1, According to documentation for **TerminateJobCommand**: "Terminates a job in a job queue. Jobs that are in the STARTING or RUNNING state are terminated, which causes them to transition to FAILED. **Jobs that have not progressed to the STARTING state are cancelled**." RUNNABLE status is before STARTING status, so it should be cancelled by TerminateJobCommand?

2, According to documentation for **CancelJobCommand**: , "A job inRUNNABLE remains in RUNNABLE until it reaches the head of the job queue. Then the job status is updated to FAILED." So CancelJobCommand should also work for cancelling, but there will be delay?

What I have tried/tested:

On a same runnable job, after calling both CancelJobCommand and TerminateJobCommand, I always get 200 status response. However, both apis could sometimes fail in that after using "aws batch list-jobs --job-status RUNNABLE --region XXXX" to check if target jobs are indeed removed from RUNNABLE list (ie, successfully canceled), I still see them appeared with status of RUNNABLE. Even after hours.

Comment: "sometimes work sometimes don't": what does it mean? what are you seeing when the cancellations "work" and when they "don't"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. When cancellation works: I get 200 status response after using both apis, and I use cmd "aws batch list-jobs --job-status RUNNABLE" to check those jobs, and they are not within runnable list. When they fail: I also get 200 response, but I can still find them with "aws batch list-jobs --job-status RUNNABLE". This happened for both apis... Which is just weird..

Comment: Could you please update your post with this information? It will help the future visitors of the site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Jobs that have not progressed to the STARTING state are cancelled. RUNNABLE status is before STARTING status, so it should be cancelled by TerminateJobCommand?

Yes, for the jobs that are still in the queue, `TerminateJob` is effectively the same as `CancelJob`.

> So `CancelJobCommand` should also work for cancelling, but there will be delay?

There will be no delay in the sense that after you have successfully issued this command, the job will never get executed.

You will still see the status as `RUNNABLE` (i. e. it will not get removed from the queue), but when it will reach the point at which it would normally execute, it will transition straight to `FAILED`.

Batch jobs can have a retry strategy set up. Normally, this would place them back into `RUNNABLE` after a predefined number of failed attempts. `CancelJob` overrides this.

In the output of [`DescribeJobs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobs.html), there are two boolean fields, `isCancelled` and `isTerminated`, which will let you know if a runnable job will never actually get run.

---

Note that "the head of the queue" the docs are talking about is quite a misleading term. The job changes from RUNNABLE to STARTING (or to FAILED if it's been cancelled) when it's actually about to be assigned to a compute unit in the cluster. Being "in the head of the queue" is one prerequisite for that, but it's not the only one.

What's probably happening is that your cluster specs don't match the job constraints. If your job calls for 4G of memory but the EC2 instances in your cluster only have 2G, then this job will never have a chance to be scheduled for execution. It will just stay in the RUNNABLE state forever.

Under the hood, the job queue relies on an [event streaming platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing#Stream_programming_libraries_and_languages), most probably Kinesis. In event streaming, events are immutable. It means that once the event is in the stream, there is nothing you can do with it. It will get to the processor and processed somehow. That's why it's not falling of the queue.

The extra state of the job being cancelled or terminated is recorded elsewhere (maybe a DynamoDB table or similar). Until very recently, AWS had not been exposing this state, but [now they do](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/aws-batch-visibility-terminated-cancelled-jobs/).

Comment: Thanks for the information! By "when it will reach the point at which it would normally execute", this means it WILL take some time for job to reach the head of the queue, right? But before "it will reach the point at which it would normally execute", the job's isCancelled or isTerminated attribute is still not changed, even we issued the command? Or am I still missing something here?

Comment: @Hang: If you cancel a job, it will set `isCancelled` to true and it will remain true, same for termination. If have a backlog of jobs, yes, it will take some time for them to reach the head of the queue. That's why it's called queue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I just checked that I cancelled a job two days ago, and its "isCancelled" attribute is True, but now it is still at "RUNNABLE" status. So that means it has been two days, and this job still has not "reached the head of the queue"?

Comment: @Hang: See the post update